# html picture element not honoring small media query

Tags: html, css, picturefill, fluid-images, picture-element

I've got a thing like this:

```
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width:1200)" srcset="big.jpg">
  <source media="(min-width:840)" srcset="small.jpg">
  <img srcset="big.jpg" alt="Test" />
</picture>
```

I'm also using [picturefill](http://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/).

My issue is that both firefox and chrome (the 2 I'm currently testing on), will load only big.jpg, even in small screens. Checked also on console's network trace.

My css sets img as basic fluid:

```
img{
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height:auto;
}
```

So what's wrong in my code?

Comment: I would use `<img>` with `srcset` and `sizes` instead. Also, aren't you missing a unit declaration on your `min-width` values?

Comment: Interesting, even [picturefill's website](http://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/) makes a request for all three images (they use three instead of two as you have) when I make my screen really small...

Comment: @I haz kode: `<img>` with srcset/sizes is not the way for art-directed pictures, afaik, because you'll not 100% sure of what the browser will choose, since they're considered only suggestions. Anyway, you're right the problem here was the lack of unit declaration! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for [I haz kode](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8157693/i-haz-kode)'s comment, the answer is: my code lacked unit declaration in media queries.

As for completeness, I also write here a better code for my use case: having a default image for small screens and different one from 840px up.

```
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width:840px)" srcset="big.jpg">
  <img srcset="small.jpg" alt="Foradori">
</picture>
```

This will work correctly and download only the right image for the current breakpoint.
Also remember we need [picturefill](http://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/) to ensure crossbrowser support.